# Библиотека для Дифференциальных уравнений

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, есть ли в С# библиотеки для работы с дифурами?
Мне необходимо программно решить дифуравнение второго порядка в частных производных( уравнение теплопроводности стержня).

Comment: Если найдёшь поищи заодно библиотеку для матриц, ну там транспонирование, перемножение... Крамер, Гаус.....

Comment: Уж не думаю что есть стандартные библиотеки от Microsoft для мат. анализа)

Comment: наберите в гугле `c# libraries solving ODE`

Comment: для работы с матрицами есть класс из System.Drawing.Drawing2D (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix?view=netframework-4.8#methods) хотя это оверкил. вряд ли вам нужен весь функционал из этого пространства имен